# mount a readonly public s3 bucket with s3fs

Tags: s3fs, minio

We have `minio` server with a public readonly bucket. I want to mount it using `s3fs` but cannot figure out how to mount it. `s3fs` always wants credentials from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mount s3fs with `-o public_bucket=1` for a public bucket.

Comment: Thanks, but I get: fuse: unknown option `public_bucket'

Comment: that must be `-o public_bucket=1`.